# Make parser include surrounding whitespace in string literals

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I wrote a Scala parser for an in-house expression language that has double quote-delimited string literals:

```
object MyParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  lazy val strLiteral = "\"" ~> """[^"]*""".r <~ "\"" ^^ {
    case x ⇒ StringLiteral(x)
  }
  // ...
}
```

(The actual code is a bit different since I support `""` as an escape sequence for a literal double quote. While this is not relevant for the discussion, it's the reason why I cannot just use `JavaTokenParsers`'s `stringLiteral`).

I noticed that the parser fails to include whitespace at the beginning and at the end of a string:

```
"a"   parsed as StringLiteral("a")
" a"  parsed as StringLiteral("a")
"a "  parsed as StringLiteral("a")
" a " parsed as StringLiteral("a")
```

I tried matching whitespace in the regex:

```
"\"" ~> """\s*[^"]*\s*""".r <~ "\""
```

and also using the explicit `whiteSpace` parser:

```
"\"" ~> whiteSpace.? ~ """[^"]*""".r ~ whiteSpace.? <~ "\""
```

but in both cases the `~>` operator has already consumed and ignored the spaces before there's a chance to read and handle them.

I know that I can set `skipWhitespace = false`, but I prefer not to, since in general I want to allow arbitrary whitespace around tokens in this language.

What's a simple and clean strategy to include surrounding whitespace in string literals?

Answer (score 1):

One option you have is to use single regexp for your string literal:

```
val stringLiteral:Parser[String] = """"([^"]*("")?)*"""".r
```

and then strip matched quotes afterwards.